# How can I change the behaviour of bindPopup

Tags: leaflet, popup

Good day everybody.

I bought a nice template and leaftlet is used to show maker.
Here is the [demo](https://bud.eco-sensors.ch/) . Actually when you clik on a marker, it open a widnows with a picture and some température value.

I would like to have all of the windows open. Of course, I am going to modify the html, to remove the picture and some information as GPS, and only keep the temperatue value. The goal is to be able to immediately see the temperature boxes below the markers. Optionaly, when I click on the marker it redirect to another page, same you click on the picture.

My first problem, I can not find the jacasvript script which work with the link of marker. The idea would be to cancel the effect of the click, or as I wrote, after we click it open the graph page instead of opening the windows.

- My first question: how can I find a do to change the action of the click, on the marker
- My second question (may be it be cancel the 1st question :) ), how can I change the behaviour of the bindpopup? Is there way "to tell" to the bindpopup, stay always open?
- My thirst question: Or can we add one or two additional nice boxes, which show always the temperature below the marker, and keep the bindPopup, as it is? That would be nice as well

Here is the code of the map [line 215](https://bud.eco-sensors.ch/assets/js/custom-map.js)

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// OpenStreetMap - Homepage
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function createHomepageOSM(_latitude,_longitude,_nbField){


    setMapHeight();

    if( document.getElementById('map') != null ){
        
        var map = L.map('map', {
            center: [_latitude,_longitude],
            zoom: 18,
            scrollWheelZoom: false
        });
            
        //L.tileLayer('http://openmapsurfer.uni-hd.de/tiles/roadsg/x={x}&y={y}&z={z}', {
        L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.fr/hot/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            //subdomains: '0123',
            maxZoom: 20,
            attribution: '<a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>'
        }).addTo(map);


        var markers = L.markerClusterGroup({
            showCoverageOnHover: false
        });

        function locateUser() {
            $('#map').addClass('fade-map');
            map.locate({setView : true})
        }
        $('.geo-location').on("click", function() {
            locateUser();
        });


        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "sql/get_map.mysql.php",
            //data:'node=node1',
            //data:{node_id:"firstnode", node2:"secondnode", node3:"thirdnode", from:"from", to:"to"}, // Send parameter to get.php
            success: result,
            error: error,
            dataType: "json"
        });
       
        function error(data)
        {
            $('body').addClass('loaded');
            alert("Error getting datas from DB");
            console.log("Error getting datas from DB");
            console.log(data);
        }
        

        function result(data){
            console.info("data:",data);

            var allMarkers=[];
            var nhtml = '<img src="assets/img/property-types/vineyard.png">';

            for (var i = 0; i < data.properties.length; i++) {

                allMarkers.push(L.latLng(data.properties[i]['la'], data.properties[i]['lo']));


 
                //data.properties[i]['b2'] = 0;

                if((data.properties[i]['b1']>=data.properties[i]['se'] && data.properties[i]['b1'] < data.properties[i]['se']+1) ||
                    (data.properties[i]['b2']>=data.properties[i]['se'] && data.properties[i]['b2'] < data.properties[i]['se']+1) ||
                    (data.properties[i]['b3']>=data.properties[i]['se'] && data.properties[i]['b3'] < data.properties[i]['se']+1) ||
                    (data.properties[i]['b4']>=data.properties[i]['se'] && data.properties[i]['b4'] < data.properties[i]['se']+1)
                )
                {
                    nhtml = '<img src="assets/img/property-types/vineyard-orange.png">';
                }

               

                if(((data.properties[i]['b1'] < data.properties[i]['se']) && data.properties[i]['b1'] != null) ||
                    ((data.properties[i]['b2'] < data.properties[i]['se']) && data.properties[i]['b2'] != null) ||
                    ((data.properties[i]['b3'] < data.properties[i]['se']) && data.properties[i]['b3'] != null) ||
                    ((data.properties[i]['b4'] < data.properties[i]['se']) && data.properties[i]['b4'] != null)
                )
                {
                
                
                    nhtml = '<img src="assets/img/property-types/vineyard-red.png">';
                }
                else{
                    nhtml = '<img src="assets/img/property-types/vineyard.png">';
                }


                    

                var _icon = L.divIcon({
                    //html: '<img src="' + locations[i][7] +'">',
                    html: nhtml,
                    iconSize:     [40, 48],
                    iconAnchor:   [20, 48],
                    popupAnchor:  [0, -48]
                });

                var title = data.properties[i]['station'];
                var marker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(data.properties[i]['la'],data.properties[i]['lo']), {
                    title: title,
                    icon: _icon
                });

                var str ='';
                if(data.properties[i]['b1'] != null)
                {
                    str = str.concat('<div class="tag price"> ' + data.properties[i]['b1'] + '°C</div>');
                }
                if(data.properties[i]['b2'] != null)
                {
                    str = str.concat('<div class="tag price"> ' + data.properties[i]['b2'] + '°C</div>');
                }
                if(data.properties[i]['b3'] != null)
                {
                    str = str.concat('<div class="tag price"> ' + data.properties[i]['b3'] + '°C</div>');
                }
                if(data.properties[i]['b4'] != null)
                {

                    str = str.concat('<div class="tag price"> ' + data.properties[i]['b4'] + '°C</div>');
                }

                
                marker.bindPopup(
                    '<div class="property">' +
                        '<a data-field=' + data.properties[i]['id_field'] +'" data-station=' + data.properties[i]['id_station'] +'" href="charts.php?field='+ data.properties[i]['id_field'] +'">' +
                            '<div class="property-image">' +

                                '<img src="img/stations/station-' + data.properties[i]['id_station'] + '.jpg">' +
                            '</div>' +
                            '<div class="overlay">' +

                                '<div class="info">' +
                                      '<h3>' + data.properties[i]['station'] + '</h3>' +
                                    '<figure>' + data.properties[i]['da'] + '</figure>' +
                                     '<figure>' + data.properties[i]['la'] + ' ' + data.properties[i]['lo'] +'</figure>' +
                                    str +
                          
                                    '<div class="tag"> ' + data.properties[i]['se'] + '°C</div>' +
                                    
                                  
                                '</div>' +
                            '</div>' +
                        '</a>' +
                    '</div>'
                );
                               
            

                markers.addLayer(marker);
            }


            if(_nbField>1){
                bounds = L.latLngBounds(allMarkers);
                map.fitBounds(bounds,{ padding: [10, 10] });
            }

            map.addLayer(markers);
            map.on('locationfound', onLocationFound);

            function onLocationFound(){
                $('#map').removeClass('fade-map');
            }

            $('body').addClass('loaded');

            setTimeout(function() {
                $('body').removeClass('has-fullscreen-map');
            }, 1000);

            $('#map').removeClass('fade-map');
            
        

        }
}
}
```

- My last question, with firefox, id possible "to track" the javascript action?

Feel free to aks complementary question to better understand and help, if I missed to provide information.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. You can add a `click` event to the marker:

```
marker.on('click',(e)=>{
   console.log(e);
});
```

2. Show all Popups:
   You need to set the options [autoClose and closeOnClick](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#popup-autoclose) to false:

```
marker.bindPopup(content,{autoClose: false, closeOnClick: false});
```

3. You can use [Tooltips](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.7.1.html#tooltip):

```
marker.bindTooltip('5.3°C', {direction: 'bottom', permanent: true});
```

4. I don't know exactly what do you mean, but it sounds like debugging. Use the `developer console` with the Debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply and help

Unfortunately 2. does not work. There is no differences. I added closeButton:true, and that works, but it's not what I need.

```
marker.bindPopup(
                    '<div class="property">' +
                        '<a data-field=' + data.properties[i]['id_field'] +'" data-station=' + data.properties[i]['id_station'] +'" href="charts.php?field='+ data.properties[i]['id_field'] +'#st-'+ data.properties[i]['id_station'] +'">' +
                            '<div class="property-image">' +

                                '<img src="img/stations/station-' + data.properties[i]['id_station'] + '.jpg">' +
                            '</div>' +
                            '<div class="overlay">' +

                                '<div class="info">' +
                                      '<h3>' + data.properties[i]['station'] + '</h3>' +
                                    '<figure>' + data.properties[i]['da'] + '</figure>' +
                                     '<figure>' + data.properties[i]['la'] + ' ' + data.properties[i]['lo'] +'</figure>' +
                                    str +
                          
                                    '<div class="tag"> ' + data.properties[i]['se'] + '°C</div>' +
                                    
                                  
                                '</div>' +
                            '</div>' +
                        '</a>' +
                    '</div>',{autoClose: true, closeOnClick: false, closeButton: true}
                );
```

I also tried the interesting option with tooltip. Bellow the above code I added

```
marker.bindTooltip('5.3°C', {direction: 'bottom', permanent: true});
```

But that print an error message

> marker.bindTooltip is not a function

Is there additionally library I have to add for tooltop, or is inlcuded into leafet.

(bindTootip would be great and enough for my need)

Thanks for helping
Cheers

Comment: I also tried marker.bindPopup("This is the Transamerica Pyramid").openPopup(); without success. But in any case, tooltip would be enough.